# Django Rest Framework - How can I authenticate a guest user?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an app where registered users can create/edit/delete tasks and edit their profiles with token authentication. I want the guest users to be also able to perform the same CRUD operations, but without accessing the profile page, and only to be able to create of maximum 10 tasks.

Since a guest user is not a registered user, therefore their "is_active" model field is False, they cannot be authenticated, at least not to my knowledge. So, the question is, is there a way to authenticate a guest user, despite their "is_acive" field being set to False?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/yunojuno/django-visitor-pass

Comment: Not exactly what I need. This visitor pass is based on an "invite" link from an already registered user.